# Jquery / Form Submission / Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a basic form that is dynamically created. I'm having an issue when I submit my form, for a split second, all checkboxes become selected.... Does anyone know why this would be happening? Is this normal? The form submits fine, but it becomes confusing for a user when they click vote and suddenly see all checkboxes checked.  (Note there may be a tiny little bit of c# in here).

It when created it looks like this:

```
<form action="/en/OnlineServices/SomeService" method="post">        
<div id="voters">
   <label><input type="checkbox" class="votebox" value="Some Name">Some Name<br></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="votebox" value="Some Name">Some Name<br></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="votebox" value="Some Name">Some Name<br></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="votebox" value="Some Name">Some Name<br></label>
</div>
<input id="VoteSubmit" type="submit" value="Vote">
    <span style="margin-left: -9999px;"><input id="Vote" name="Vote" type="text" value=""></span>
    <span style="margin-left: -9999px;"><input id="Language" name="Language" type="text" value=""></span>
```

And the JS

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#Vote").val("")
    $("#voters").after("<input id='VoteSubmit' type='submit' value='Vote' />");

    var language = "@(bool.Parse(res.IsFrench) ? "FR" : "EN")";   // Sets var language as user languge
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);

    });
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);

        var a = $(this).val();
        $("input#Vote").val(a); // Inserts cows name into hidden field
    $("#Language").val(language);// Inserts language  into hidden field
    });



});
</script>
```

Comment: Any JavaScript associated with the HTML file, that works on the checkboxes?

Comment: Yes their is. Just editing the post, forgot to icnlude it...

Comment: Check your statement:  if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {..} It is checking all the checkboxes. Instead use $(this).is(":checked")

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be this --

```
if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
}
```

That looks like you want to check the "checked" property, and if it is, then addClass.  `$("input[type=checkbox]")` is going to wrap all the checkboxes, so a change to any one of them will activate the event code, but $(this) inside the function will refer to the wrapped set, which is all the checkboxes.  That if statement will return `this` which evaluates to truthy, so that's probably it.  Try

```
if($(this).prop("checked")) {
```

Comment: Thanks, but there neither JGrubb's or Anup Vasudeva's appear to work for me. Same issue.

Comment: I just noticed that you're setting `$(this).prop("checked", true);` right before you do that if check.  Why?  Also, I think the problem is that `this` inside that whole function refers to all checkboxes, not just the one I think you want.  if you `console.log(this)` inside that function, what do you get?

Comment: I've simplified the js as much as i could, but I'm still getting this problem. The "this" values are working correctly.

Comment: Should `var language = "@(bool.Parse(res.IsFrench) ? "FR" : "EN")";` instead be `var language = "@(bool.Parse(res.IsFrench))" ? "FR" : "EN";`? edit: what I mean is, was that a typo in the question or is it that way in the script, because that's definitely not right. edit2: Oh.

Comment: Nope, pretty sure that is correct, this is a c# / asp.net applicaiton. Probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out?  If so, what was it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a problem with your jQuery codes as the following will trigger the `change` event which will set all the checkboxes back to unchecked state

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

Also you missed a semicolon in the second line

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#Vote").val("");
    $("#voters").after("<input id='VoteSubmit' type='submit' value='Vote' />");

    var language = "@(bool.Parse(res.IsFrench) ? 'FR' : 'EN')";   // Sets var language as user languge
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);

    });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);

        var a = $(this).val();
        $("input#Vote").val(a); // Inserts cows name into hidden field
        $("#Language").val(language);// Inserts language  into hidden field
    });
});
</script>
```